# Logger in Eclipse plugin with earlyStartup

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have a eclipse plugin which implements BundleActivator,IStartup.
I need to log the error that occur in earlyStartup(), I need the .log file to be updated for every error.
I am unable to find any logging facility for earlyStartup eclipse plugin.

If anyone has any ideas about the same,please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write to the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory using:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");

IStatus status = new Status(IStatus.ERROR, "plugin id", msg or null, throwable or null);

Platform.getLog(bundle).log(status);
```

The first parameter to `Status` can be `IStatus.INFO`, `WARNING` or `ERROR`.